# Reasons for extension installation being so complicated in TYPO3?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I'm just in the decision process what CMS to choose, so I'm trying TYPO3. I decided to install yag extension (yet another gallery). First surprise was that I had to install dependencies manually. After successful installation, I selected "Gallery" in the left pane, and got this error in the right pane

> No Settings for the YAG Gallery were found on the selected page.
>   Please select a page where the static template for YAG is included. Or
>   include the static template of YAG on this page.

Chinese for me. How can I "include static template"? I googled several tutorials for this ([#1](http://typo3tutorials.com/index.php?id=109), [#2](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/mm_forum/1.9.2/view/1/2/), [#3](http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_add_static_extension_templates)), none worked (version 4.7.2). Finally I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4V5Y7ARdz0) which helped me. But it hasn't solved the problem yet! I got another error telling me, that I should somehow update the configuration (WTH?). Another googling and I finally managed to do it via Extension manager, Configuration tab, Update.

Why is such a simple thing like installing an extension so complicated? Why such complications for the user? If the package requires to install some template and update configuration, why it is not part of the installation process?

Comment: Do you expect an answer to your question? It appears you already solved the technical problem you had

Comment: @Felipe, yes, I asked a clear question - I asked for reasons why it's so complicated - and I expect an answer. Well, the fact that the question is hard to answer doesn't make it "Not a real question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is clear, there are 5k+ of extensions in 20k+ versions, written for many different TYPO3 versions, trough long years, trough different programming patterns by thousands of developers.

If there was no some 'interface' for connecting them, the TYPO3 would be just useless.

If you expect the good results in few days I must disappoint you, TYPO3 learning curve is long I think you need to waste at least 3, 4 weeks to get more comfortable with it.

BTW `including statics from extension` is the very first step for almost any good ext in TYPO3's repository.

Comment: Thank you Marcus! I don't get your note `If there was no some 'interface' for connecting them ...` in context of my question. Is there any reason why the package's post-installation script couldn't do all the necessary steps for me?

Comment: Wrong, keep in mind that you can for an example host many services with one T3 instance, and use YAG only for one of them. In such scenario why should the YAG's config be included automatically to the other `page-tree-branches`? OK, I understand that could be annoying for very first steps with small tests or implementation, but believe me, that when project is growing possibility of including setup for some extension only in selected branches/pages is a blessing.

Comment: Thank you Marcus this is a satisfying answer. I don't understand completely but I trust you :)

Comment: Anyway, couldn't typo just include the YAG's config automatically to those pages, where the YAG is used?

Comment: Marcus, you say 3-4 weeks to get comfortable with TYPO... you mean including the Typoscript or just get comfortable with the backend GUI?

Comment: @Tomas GUI + TypoScript basics, I think that after that time it's quite possible to create good projects of your own choice, not only 'implementing' ready-to-use templates. You'll need to spend several next months to find which extensions are you favorite, and also how to create own extensions - which possibility is de facto the most important benefit of using TYPO3

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the extension, if the settings are done automatically. But if you have special needs, such automatic settings could cause a lot of trouble. So i personally prefer not to use automatic settings (older extensions often do!).
It depends on the extension, if autmatic settings hurt on the long run or not.

And keep in mind, that installing an extension is not an editor task, but an administrator task.